# Font Awesome Icon doesnt get displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I'm building an expanding search bar, unfortunately the search icon from [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) is not showing.

Here is the code:

```js
;(function(window) {
  'use strict';

  // EventListener | @jon_neal | //github.com/jonathantneal/EventListener
  !window.addEventListener && window.Element && (function() {
    function addToPrototype(name, method) {
      Window.prototype[name] = HTMLDocument.prototype[name] = Element.prototype[name] = method;
    }

    var registry = [];

    addToPrototype("addEventListener", function(type, listener) {
      var target = this;

      registry.unshift({
        __listener: function(event) {
          event.currentTarget = target;
          event.pageX = event.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
          event.pageY = event.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
          event.preventDefault = function() {
            event.returnValue = false
          };
          event.relatedTarget = event.fromElement || null;
          event.stopPropagation = function() {
            event.cancelBubble = true
          };
          event.relatedTarget = event.fromElement || null;
          event.target = event.srcElement || target;
          event.timeStamp = +new Date;

          listener.call(target, event);
        },
        listener: listener,
        target: target,
        type: type
      });

      this.attachEvent("on" + type, registry[0].__listener);
    });

    addToPrototype("removeEventListener", function(type, listener) {
      for (var index = 0, length = registry.length; index < length; ++index) {
        if (registry[index].target == this && registry[index].type == type && registry[index].listener == listener) {
          return this.detachEvent("on" + type, registry.splice(index, 1)[0].__listener);
        }
      }
    });

    addToPrototype("dispatchEvent", function(eventObject) {
      try {
        return this.fireEvent("on" + eventObject.type, eventObject);
      } catch (error) {
        for (var index = 0, length = registry.length; index < length; ++index) {
          if (registry[index].target == this && registry[index].type == eventObject.type) {
            registry[index].call(this, eventObject);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  })();

  // http://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/989439
  function mobilecheck() {
    var check = false;
    (function(a) {
      if (/(android|ipad|playbook|silk|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) check = true
    })(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);
    return check;
  }

  // http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/polyfills-and-prototypes/
  !String.prototype.trim && (String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  });

  function UISearch(el, options) {
    this.el = el;
    this.inputEl = el.querySelector('form > input.sb-search-input');
    this._initEvents();
  }

  UISearch.prototype = {
    _initEvents: function() {
      var self = this,
        initSearchFn = function(ev) {
          ev.stopPropagation();
          // trim its value
          self.inputEl.value = self.inputEl.value.trim();

          if (!classie.has(self.el, 'sb-search-open')) { // open it
            ev.preventDefault();
            self.open();
          } else if (classie.has(self.el, 'sb-search-open') && /^\s*$/.test(self.inputEl.value)) { // close it
            ev.preventDefault();
            self.close();
          }
        }

      this.el.addEventListener('click', initSearchFn);
      this.el.addEventListener('touchstart', initSearchFn);
      this.inputEl.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
        ev.stopPropagation();
      });
      this.inputEl.addEventListener('touchstart', function(ev) {
        ev.stopPropagation();
      });
    },
    open: function() {
      var self = this;
      classie.add(this.el, 'sb-search-open');
      // focus the input
      if (!mobilecheck()) {
        this.inputEl.focus();
      }
      // close the search input if body is clicked
      var bodyFn = function(ev) {
        self.close();
        this.removeEventListener('click', bodyFn);
        this.removeEventListener('touchstart', bodyFn);
      };
      document.addEventListener('click', bodyFn);
      document.addEventListener('touchstart', bodyFn);
    },
    close: function() {
      this.inputEl.blur();
      classie.remove(this.el, 'sb-search-open');
    }
  }

  // add to global namespace
  window.UISearch = UISearch;
})(window);
```

```css
.sb-search {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 0%;
  min-width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: width 0.3s;
  transition: width 0.3s;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.sb-search-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 20px 65px 20px 20px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
.sb-search-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #efb480;
}
.sb-search-input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #efb480;
}
.sb-search-input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #efb480;
}
.sb-search-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #efb480;
}
.fa.fa-search,
.sb-search-submit {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sb-search-submit {
  background: #fff;
  /* IE needs this */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  /* IE 8 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  /* IE 5-7 */
  opacity: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  z-index: -1;
}
.fa.fa-search {
  border: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  background: #efb480;
  z-index: 90;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.fa.fa-search:before {
  content: "\e000";
}
/* Open state */

.sb-search.sb-search-open,
.no-js .sb-search {
  width: 100%;
}
.sb-search.sb-search-open .fa.fa-search,
.no-js .sb-search .fa.fa-search {
  background: #da6d0d;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 11;
}
.sb-search.sb-search-open .sb-search-submit,
.no-js .sb-search .sb-search-submit {
  z-index: 90;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="nav-btn">
  <div id="sb-search" class="sb-search">
    <form>
      <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Enter your search term..." type="text" value="" name="search" id="search" />
      <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="" />
      <button class="sb-icon-search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I only started front-end development a few weeks ago and I'd appreciate some help! :) I included the `font-awesome.min.css` stylesheet. Its working in other lines.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0wm440gn/4/

The JS works fine in my files, I don't understand why JSFiddle doesn't do it properly. But my problem must be somewhere in the Markup/CSS.

Comment: on the jsfiddle, you needed to include the font-awesome css as an external url

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is on line 88 of your CSS file, where it says:

```
.fa.fa-search:before {
    content: "\e000";
}
```

That's not the correct unicode character, and if you're using fontawesome you don't need it anyway. Delete those lines and fontawesome will take care of you.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in your CSS.

You have the following rule:

```css
.fa.fa-search:before {
    content: "\e000";
}
```

In the `font-awesome.css` file, `.fa-search` is defined as:

```
.fa-search:before {
    content: "\f002";
}
```

Since your selector, in your CSS, has a higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), the default value of `\F002` is being replaced with `\E000`.

I removed this and the glyph appeared correctly.

---

### Broken

```css
.fa.fa-search:before {
  content: "\e000";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button class="sb-icon-search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
```

### Fixed

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="sb-icon-search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just include the external reference to Fontawesome:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

and remove the lines

```
.fa.fa-search:before {
    content: "\e000";
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0wm440gn/11/)